# how to delete the data in object object from react (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have data in the following format: What if I want to delete "2019-06-28"?

i make the data by this code

```
  let obj = this.state._markedDates.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {
                    [v]: {
                        selected: true,
                        marked: true
                    }
  }), {});
  this.setState({marked: obj});
```

and now i want to delete inside of object Can anyone help me? i make the code in react native

```
Object {
  "2019-06-20": Object {
    "marked": true,
    "selected": true,
  },
  "2019-06-28": Object {
    "marked": true,
    "selected": true,
  },
}
```

Comment: delete Object ["2019-06-20"]?,that's not a proper json

Comment: Your object isn't working.

Comment: i'm sorry i missed a information @SaurabhAgrawal 
and i updated

Comment: yes i agree but when i marking date in react-native calendar i have to fit the form @Shubh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete keys from your object

```
const a = {
  "2019-06-20": {
    "marked": true,
    "selected": true,
  },
  "2019-06-28": {
    "marked": true,
    "selected": true,
  },
};

Object.keys(a).forEach(keyToBeDeleted => {
  // keyToBeDeleted has `2019-06-20` and `2019-06-28`
  if (keyToBeDeleted === '2019-06-28') {
     delete a[keyToBeDeleted]; // this will delete the key in your object as it is in loop. Treat your logic as per your requirements
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  "2019-06-20": {
    "marked": true,
    "selected": true,
  },
  "2019-06-28": {
    "marked": true,
    "selected": true,
  },
}


delete a["2019-06-20"]
```